# Omitting ansible's argument basing on variable

Tags: ansible

I want to maintain users with ansible. I use `user` module but I want to have some non-unique user ids.
Now I have a dictionary like this:

```
users:
    user: { password: "HASH", shell: "/bin/zsh", home: "/home/user", uid: -1, non-unique: "no" }
    userroot: { password: "HASH1", shell: "/bin/zsh", home: "/home/userroot", uid: 0, non-unique: "yes" }
```

I'm creating users like that:

```
- name: Create users
  user: name={{ item.key }} createhome=yes shell={{ item.value.shell }} password={{ item.value.password }} home="{{ item.value.home }}" append=yes state=present 
  with_dict: "{{users}}"
```

Question is how to add a logic that will specify `uid` argument when it is set to value greater or equal than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way how to decide this by greater than/equal uid number is to have two different resources with conditional `when`.

But if you don't need to have `uid: -1`, something like this can work. Just get rid of `uid` and `non_unique` values in user variables:

```
- name: Create users
    user:
      name={{ item.key }}
      createhome=yes
      shell={{ item.value.shell }}
      password={{ item.value.password }}
      home="{{ item.value.home }}"
      append=yes
      state=present
      uid="{{ item.value.uid | default(omit) }}"
      non_unique="{{ item.value.non_unique | default('no') }}" 
    with_dict: "{{users}}"
```

And than not use uid and non_unique (pay attantion to this variable, there have to be `_` instead of `-`) in common users:

```
user: { password: "HASH", shell: "/bin/zsh", home: "/home/user" }
userroot: { password: "HASH1", shell: "/bin/zsh", home: "/home/userroot", uid: 0, non_unique: "yes" }
```

Comment: Thanks! filter `default(omit)` is exactly what I was looking for! More info [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters).